# PHP MailTrap Docker

Tags: php, docker, email, telnet, mailtrap

I am having a connection issue to Mailtrap from my PHP instance. I currently have such in my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context : ./
      dockerfile : Dockerfile
      network: host

    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    expose:
      - "9000"

  mail:
    container_name: sys_mail
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: eaudeweb/mailtrap:latest
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8125:80"
      - "127.0.0.1:2525:25"
    environment:
      - MT_USER=mailtrap
      - MT_PASSWD=mailtrap
      - MT_MAILBOX_LIMIT=512000001
      - MT_MESSAGE_LIMIT=102400001
```

I am able to connect on local to to mailtrap via 127.0.0.1:8125, I am also able to connect via telnet as such: `telnet localhost 2525`

But I am unable to connect and send email via smtp from my php container. My apps SMTP configuration is as such:

```
host: mail
login: mailtrap
password: mailtrap
port: 2525
```

The error is `SMTP connect() failed.`

What might be doing wrong in this setup?

Comment: The mail service does not have a network defined. It is possible they might not be on the same network. Use `docker network inspect`

Comment: @JayBlanchard They are on the same network.